# Prove that if $A$ has integer entries, $|\det A| = 1$, then the polyhedron formed by $A$ does not contain integer points.

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, determinant, volume, integer-lattices

> Given $n$ vectors $v_1 , v_2 , v_3 , \dots, v_n \in \mathbb{R}^n$ with integer entries in each vector. 
>  Prove that if $|\det(v_1 , v_2 , \dots , v_n)| = 1$, then the polyhedron $Ov_1v_2\dots v_n$ does not have any points with integer coordinates inside it, except the vertices.

---

For example,

[image: picture here]

**My idea**

Use determinant to prove that $$\det A =  \text{Volume of the paralelipiped spanned by }A $$

and because $\det A$ has integer value, we have $\min|\det A| = 1$. Then conclude that the parallelepiped spanned by $A$ is the smallest. So, if $A$ has any other integer points inside it, it will contain another smaller parallelepiped, which is conflicted with the previous statement. But here we have to consider the polyhedron, which is something I'm stuck with.

Comment: So for $n=3$ the polyhedron is a tetrahedron?

Comment: Note that the minimum for $|\det(A)|$ is not $1$ unless you are claiming some sort of linear independence. I'm not entirely sure what argument you are trying here, are you attempting a contradiction proof? Can you lay out a few more details of the approach :)

Comment: A point of terminology : it should be better to replace "the polyhedron $Ov_1v_2…v_n$" by "the convex hull of $\{0,v_1,v_2,\cdots v_n\}$"

Comment: Hint: If $w$ is a lattice point (i.e., a point with integer coordinates) inside the polyhedron, then consider the determinants $Owv_2v_3\cdots v_n$, $Ov_1wv_3\cdots v_n$ and so on (i.e., the polyhedra obtained from $Ov_1v_2\cdots v_n$ by replacing one non-origin vertex with $w$). These determinants are integers, but they are precisely the coefficients of the representation of $w$ as a convex combination of $v_1, v_2, \ldots, v_n$. What convex combinations have integer coefficients?

Comment: @darijgrinberg I understand to the part that they're integers, but how can they be the coefficients of representation of $w$ as a convex combination ? Because, first, the coefficients of a convex combination need to be positive, we can't show it yet. Second, we don't know if they can sum up to $1$ ?

Comment: @bobaj: You're working it from the wrong side. If $w = \lambda_1 v_1 + \lambda_2 v_2 + \cdots + \lambda_n v_n$, then replacing $v_i$ by $w$ means that the $i$-th column of the matrix is scaled by $\lambda_i$ and then transformed further by adding $\lambda_j$ times the $j$-th column to it for all $j \neq i$. This affects its determinant by multiplying it by $\lambda_i$.

Comment: @darijgrinberg yes I understand that, but I don't get the point of convex combination, from what I've studied, does it mean that all $\lambda_i$ must sum up to $1$ ?

Comment: @bobaj that's right. These $\lambda_i$ are called barycentric coordinates.

Comment: @JeanMarie I think involving barycentric coordinates here will only give rise another problem that we need to prove this barycentric coordinates theorem. Can you please write out the whole explaination of this for me please?

Answer (score 3):

Let us assume on the contrary that such an integer coordinates point $M$ exists inside the polyhedron.

Being in the (closed) polyhedron means :

$$M=\sum \lambda_k v_k \text{with all} \ \lambda_k \ge 0 \ \text{and} \ \sum \lambda_k=1 \tag{1}$$

(principle of barycentric coordinates).

(1) is equivalent to a linear system with integer entries:

$$\begin{cases}\lambda_1 v_{1,1}+\cdots \lambda_n v_{1,n}&=&m_1\\
\cdots\cdots\cdots \\
\lambda_1 v_{n,1}+\cdots \lambda_n v_{n,n}&=&m_n\\
\end{cases}\tag{2}$$

Let us consider the value of $\lambda_1$ as given by Cramer's formula:

$$\lambda_1=\frac{D_1}{D}=\pm D_1$$

where $D_1$ is itself an integer. Indeed, $D$ is obtained by replacing in main determinant $D$, its first column by the column of the coordinates $m_k$ of $M$.

What we have done for $\lambda_1$ is valid for any $\lambda_k$. Therefore

$$\text{All } \ \lambda_k \in \mathbb{Z}$$

But taking into account the fact (see (1)) that $\sum \lambda_k=1$:

- either only one of the $\lambda_k$s is non-zero, which implies that this $lambda_k$ is $1$ ; in this case, $M$ coincides with one of the vertices of the polyhedron.
- or more than one of the $\lambda_k$s is non-zero. In this case, due agein to relationship $\sum \lambda_k = 1$, one of the $\lambda_k$s is negative. But the "theory" of barycentric coordinates implies that such a point $M$ is outside the polyhedron. Contradiction.