# Prove that if A has integer entries, A does not contain any lattice point except it's vertices, then |det(A)| = 1

Tags: determinant, affine-geometry

This is an extension of [this question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4563763/prove-that-if-a-has-integer-entries-det-a-1-then-the-polyhedron-forme)

That question stated that if A is a matrix with $n$ integer vectors $v_i$, $|det(A)| = 1$ then the polyhedron formed by $v_i$ does not contain any lattice point inside it.

So what about the backward preposition : if A has $n$ independent integer vectors, the polyhedron does not contain any lattice point inside it, can we show that then $|det(A)| = 1$ ?

My idea is using the affine combination, we can prove if vector $w$ lies inside the polyhedron formed by $A$, specify $B_i$ as matrix A with vector $w$ replacing $v_i$ .
Then $\det(A) \geq \det (B_i)$ but again, I'm stuck here.

Comment: A cute(?) proof in the $2 \times 2$ case: if the parallelogram spanned by $A$ contains no lattice points other than the (four) vertices, including on the boundary, its area by [Pick's theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pick%27s_theorem) is $0 + 4/2 - 1 = 1$. But its area is also $\lvert \det(A) \rvert$.

Comment: (Of course this might arguably be circular if you go about proving Pick's theorem by decomposing polygons into triangles of area $1/2$, since those triangles are essentially the aforementioned parallelograms cut in two. But there are proofs that avoid this.)

Comment: How about this argument - determinant has to be an integer. At the same time absolute value of determinant represents volume spanned by columns (or rows). If there is an integer point inside then there would be a matrix with integer entries and smaller volume.

Answer (score 3):

Notice it's not enough to know just that no lattice points are in the interior; consider rectangle $(1,0), (0,2)$ which has no lattice points strictly inside but does have extra lattice points on its edges, and has determinant 2. What we can actually prove:

Given a non-singular $n \times n$ matrix $A$ with integer entries, call its column vectors $v_1, \ldots, v_n$. If the closed $n$-parallelepiped having $v_i$ as edges includes no lattice points other than its $2^n$ vertices, then $|\det A| = 1$.

The closed parallelepiped is the set of points $$x = \sum_{i=1}^n \lambda_i v_i$$ where each coefficient $\lambda_i$ is a real number $0 \leq \lambda_i \leq 1$. The vertices are the points where all the $\lambda_i$ values are either $0$ or $1$.

Now consider any integer vector $x = (x_1, \ldots, x_n) \in \mathbb{Z}^n$. Since $A$ is non-singular, we can define $y \in \mathbb{R}^n$ as $y = (y_1,\ldots, y_n) = A^{-1} x$. Writing the matrix equation $A y = x$ in terms of the vectors $v_i$ gives

$$\sum_{i=1}^n y_i v_i = x$$

Replace the coefficients $y_i$ with their integer parts to define

$$ z = \sum_{i=1}^n \lfloor y_i \rfloor v_i $$
$$ x-z = \sum_{i=1}^n (y_i - \lfloor y_i\rfloor) v_i $$

Since every $\lfloor y_i \rfloor$ and all coordinates of every $v_i$ are integers, $z$ is another integer vector, and so is $x-z$. For any real $y_i$ we have $0 \leq y_i - \lfloor y_i \rfloor < 1$, so $x-z$ satisfies the description of a point in the closed parallelepiped. But the only integer vector / lattice points in the closed parallelepiped are its vertices, so $y_i - \lfloor y_i \rfloor \in \{0,1\}$. The only remaining possibility is that every $y_i = \lfloor y_i \rfloor$, so $y = A^{-1} x$ is also an integer vector.

So $A^{-1} x$ has integer coordinates whenever $x$ does. Then in particular this is true for the basis vectors $x = (0,\ldots,0,1,0,\ldots,0)$. This shows the column vectors of $A^{-1}$ have integer coordinates, so $A^{-1}$ has all integer entries. Finally, we know that $\det A$ and $\det A^{-1}$ are non-zero integers, and
$$(\det A)(\det A^{-1}) = \det(A A^{-1}) = \det I = 1 $$
This requires $|\det A| = |\det A^{-1}| = 1$.